# How can I get element from json array in ionic 3 angular?

Tags: json, ionic-framework

I have a problem about getting an element of an array which is in json form.

```
loadPeople(){
  this.myProvider.load()
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.array= data;

   });
}
```

`this.eventDate=new Date(this.array[0].start_time);`

When I run this I am getting an error like following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘0’ of undefined

Comment: share your provider response.

Comment: you need to share useful information, which in this case is your `data` so that people can help you better mate.